# Pass argument in macro

Tags: macros

I have a macro that is repeatedly called in my document

```
\newcommand\foo[1]{Process #1}
\newcommand\var[2]{Do something with #1 and #2, and then call '\foo{#2}', and again '\foo{#2}', and once again '\foo{#2}'}
```

The macro `foo` is expanded many times inside `var` with the *same* argument, one may think that passing the argument is just redundant, and could be possibly avoided.

*Question*: Is it possible to have a version of `foo` such that when `var` is defined as

```
\newcommand\var[2]{Do something with #1 and #2, and then call '\foo', and again '\foo', and once again '\foo'}
```

would lead to the result of the first example?

> MWE

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\newcommand\foo[1]{Process #1}
\newcommand\var[2]{Do something with #1 and #2, and then call '\foo{#2}', and again '\foo{#2}', and once again '\foo{#2}'}

\begin{document}

\var{x}{y}

\end{document}
```

And this is the output
[image]

I would like to have the same result, after defining `var` as

```
\newcommand\var[2]{Do something with #1 and #2, and then call '\foo', and again '\foo', and once again '\foo'}
```

Comment: Could you please provide a small minimum working example, for us to better see what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Absolutely, I just added it

Comment: @marmot Do you mean something like `\newcommand\foo{Process \noexpand{#1}}`? It doesn't work, right? I've try a bunch of combinations of `edef`s and `\expandafter`s but I cannot make it work

Comment: Something close: `\renewcommand\var[2]{\def\foo{Process #2}Do something with #1 and #2, and then call '\foo', and again '\foo', and once again '\foo'}`

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Thanks for the answer, do you think it is possible without adding a redefinition of `foo` inside `var`?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I see no way to get `#2` or its equivalent value into `\foo` without doing *something* with `#2` to save it somewhere.  But that can only occur after `\var` is invoked.

Comment: Your requirement is a bit confusing though. Why not just do this: `\renewcommand\var[2]{Do something with #1 and #2, and then call '\foo', and again '\foo', and once again '\foo'}
\newcommand\setvar[2]{\def\foo{Process #2}\var{#1}{#2}}
\setvar{x}{y}`.  This way, `\var` is defined as you want...the only catch is that you invoke `\setvar` instead of `\var`.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I see, thanks for your time. If you add these comments as an answer I will gladly accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OP asked me to convert comments into an answer.  None of which give exactly what the OP was hoping for.

The problem is that I see no way to get `#2` or its equivalent value into `\foo` without doing something with `#2` to save it somewhere. But that can only occur after `\var` is invoked or via some pre-`\var` macro invocation.

I show both these alternatives in the MWE below.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\begin{document}
Original approach of OP

\newcommand\foo[1]{Process #1}
\newcommand\var[2]{Do something with #1 and #2, and then call '\foo{#2}', and again '\foo{#2}', and once again '\foo{#2}'}

\var{x}{y}

\hrulefill

Requires a leading \verb|\def| inside of \verb|\var|

\renewcommand\var[2]{\def\foo{Process #2}Do something with #1 and #2, and then call '\foo', and again '\foo', and once again '\foo'}

\var{x}{y}

\hrulefill

Defines \verb|\var| as desired, but requires invocation of \verb|\setvar|

\renewcommand\var[2]{Do something with #1 and #2, and then call '\foo', and again '\foo', and once again '\foo'}

\newcommand\setvar[2]{\def\foo{Process #2}\var{#1}{#2}}

\setvar{x}{y}
\end{document}
```

[image]